# Multiplication chart

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I am attempting to make a multiplication chart like the one in the picture, I am fairly new to coding and have no idea where to even start. I have included an image with the output I have so far, as well as the code below.
Any help would be appreciated.

[Output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMgR2.png)

```
Public Class frmL24
    Private Sub btnCreateChart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateChart.Click
        Dim j As Integer = 1
        Dim i As Integer = 1

        While (j <= 5)
            While (i <= 5)

                lstChart.Items.Add(String.Format(i * j))

                i += 1

            End While

            i = 1

            j += 1
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) And [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/12672179). Also this might be of use [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/12672179)

Comment: If you still have issues after following all those then I'll more than happy to help because then you can format this question to be much better and more enticing to help with :3

Comment: You'll have to change how you think of this. In the picture you showed us, the numbers are (probably) not related to their row/column header, but written as formatted strings so they look like a grid. You have to determine how to write one line of this grid, then automate this logic so you can loop it over all the lines you need (of course now I see that this lab is about nested loops... that's indeed the idea!).

Comment: Do you have to use `While` loops? This seems an obvious candidate for `For` loops.

Comment: Yes, I do, I have updated what I have now but I am still far from right. I have no experience with loops.

Comment: Why are you hard-coding the values instead of doing it in code?  A multiplication table is a pretty simple task using loops, which you should have covered in your classes. I doubt your instructor is going to accept the code you've posted here. If that's the only way you can see to do this, you need to let that instructor know that you're not understanding the course material and need help.

Comment: I changed my code just trying anything, I updated it now. What's showing now is what I originally had.

Comment: "Just trying anything" is "coding by trial and error" and it wont get you very far. I suggest you write the necessary algorithm out in comments, using the language you think in and *then* translate to VB. If you were 4 lessons into french class noone would expect you to think in french; you'd think in english, arrange a sentence the way a french person would say it ("the balloon red") and then you would translate it ("le ballon rouge"). Don't try to think in VB; it's impossible right now.Write an essay plan (algorithm in comments)so you don't lose track of where you're going, then implement it

Answer (score 0):

Start piecemeal and build it up. Here's the algorithm for a loop that emits a count from 1 to 10

```
'Start with a variable inited to 1
'while that variable is less than or equal to 10
  'print out the variable (by print I mean "add it onto the end of a textbox text")
  'increment the variable
'loop
```

Here's an algorithm that prints out a times table:

```
'have a variable for the times table we're doing, start with the 1 times table, call the variable "timestable"

'Start with a variable inited to 1, call it "number"
'while "number" is less than or equal to 10
  'print out the result of "number" multiplied by "timestable"
  'increment the value of "number"
'loop
```

Hopefully you can see this is just a minor evolution of the first algo. You set timestable to be 1, it prints the same thing the first one did. You set it to 2, it prints the 2 times table etc

Now modify the algo again, this time using a loop to change the timestable variable ten times:

```
'have a variable for the times table we're doing, start with the 1 times table, call the variable "timestable"

'while "timestable" is less than or equal to 10

  'Start with a variable inited to 1, call it "number"
  'while "number" is less than or equal to 10
    'print out the result of "number" multiplied by "timestable"
    'increment the value of "number"
  'loop

  'increment the "timestable" variable
'loop
```

This will now print out the times tables from 1 to 10

You probably no just have a few formatting things to take care of. If you have literally followed these instructions then your output will look like:

```
12345678910
2468101214161820
```

You could add a space between:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Still not very well aligned though, is it? We could do with some logic, because this is a bit simplistic:

```
'print out the result of "number" multiplied by "timestable"
```

Perhaps this would work better:

```
'calculate the result of "number" multiplied by "timestable"
'if the result is less than 10, print 2 spaces then the result
'else print 1 space then the result
```

Suddenly we get:

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Then you just have some fluff to add around printing headers etc..

You'll note I haven't posted any code, because this is your homework, not mine. I know how to do it, but if I do it for you it robs you of the opportunity to learn this process yourself. Your end result absolutely should have a bunch of comments in like the comments i've written here (your version of the algorithm as you understand it), with code underneath. Even if you never get it working as the spec demands, you should hand in the code and the comments so the instructor can see where your thinking went wrong (the algo in comments is wrong) or where your thinking was right but your answer (the code you wrote) was wrong. This is like "showing your working out" in math exams

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to use the wrong type of loop. Explain this to your instructor.

It also makes no sense to use the wrong type of control to display your data. A `ListBox` is for lists. Your data is more like a table than a list. A `DataGridView` is meant to display tabular data. Add a `DataGridView` to your Form.

A `DataTable` is a class in the .Net Framework that is meant to be an in memory representation of a table (columns and rows). You can fill it in memory and then use it as the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView` to display the data. This is more efficient than continually changing the display as you add data.

This exercise should be a good introduction to `DataTable` which is a very useful tool when you start database work.

The `For` loop increments `i` (or whatever you name your variable) by default by 1.

First we create a `DataTable` just like any other variable only with the `New` keyword since we are creating an instance of a class. Next add the columns you need. The first column is X and then the numbers 1 to 10.

Now add the data (the rows). The first and second column of each row is just `i`. The third column is `i` x 2 and so on..

Lastly, we set the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView` to our filled `DataTable` (`dt`) and tidy up a bit to make it look nice. There are a slew of properties to customize the appearance of a `DataGridView`.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("X", GetType(Integer))
    For i = 1 To 10
        dt.Columns.Add(i.ToString, GetType(Integer))
    Next
    For i = 1 To 10
        dt.Rows.Add(i, i, i * 2, i * 3, i * 4, i * 5, i * 6, i * 7, i * 8, i * 9, i * 10)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeRows()
    'To make the numbers line up nicely
    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        col.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @CaiusJard You are probably right but maybe my single paragraph summary of what a DataTable is will spark some curiosity.